# Datatables - Can't sort by column different than string type

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I have a datatable with 'date' column of type String. Now, when I want to sort by it, it's obviously not sorting properly for obvious reasons, so I changed the sType to 'date' and everything is fine.
The problem however is when I change the sType from string to something else, I cannot sort by this column anymore. Initial sort after page load is sorted and fine, but I can't click the column anymore to sort by it. It behaves like bSortable is false, but it isn't (debugged it). bSort is also true. 
Moreover, I've tried implementing custom comparators, including sort plugins etc. same results. 
Any ideas what might be causing the problem?

**EDIT**:
My datatable init process:

```
$('#scanDataTable').dataTable({
     "bJQueryUI": true,
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     "sDom": '<""l>t<"F"fp>',
     "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
     "iDisplayLength": "100",
     "aoColumnDefs": [
          {"sType": "date", "aTargets": [0]}
     ]
});
```

If the "sType" parameter is string, clicking on the column header switches between asc and desc sorting (but it's string so the sorting is incorrect). After switching "sType" to date or anything else than string, clicking on table header does nothing.
As I mentioned earlier, I tried with "bSortable": true in column 0 options and "bSort": true in dataTable options, and imported custom sorting plugins, but it doesn't change anything. My date format is: 17.11.2014 21:54:39.

**Important:** After messing a bit with aaSorting, I noticed that both asc and desc sorting is the same which probably means that the sorting itself is the problem, and not the table options.

Comment: "_Any ideas what might be causing the problem?_" It is impossible to say when we dont have any code to look at :) Please add your script and example of markup to the question.

Comment: I didn't include any code because there is really nothing special to show. It's just a regular simplest datatable but fair enough. I'll add some code when I get home.

Comment: Added some more info along with dataTable options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format is not compatible with `new Date()` or `Data.parse()`, thats why the column sorting becomes "frozen" when you try to apply the default `date` type to the column. It is trying to sort a bunch of `NaN` strings. So you must create an appropriate plugin yourself.

Here is an example, a `sikor-date` that parses your format `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss` to standard UTC time :

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "sikor-date-pre": function(a) {
        var dateParts = a.split('.'),
        time = a.split(' ')[1].split(':'),
        year = parseInt(dateParts[2])-1900,
        month = parseInt(dateParts[1])-1,
        day = parseInt(dateParts[0]),
        hours = parseInt(time[0]),
        mins = parseInt(time[1]),
        secs = parseInt(time[2]);
        return Date.UTC(year, month, day, hours, mins, secs);
    },
    "sikor-date-asc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "sikor-date-desc": function(a,b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

The entire date string is splitted into logical parts, parsed to integers and then converted to a compareable number with [**`Date.UTC()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/nm261eyn/**

This sorting plugin should work with all versions of dataTables. Use it as

```js
"aoColumnDefs": [
    {"sType": "sikor-date", "aTargets": [0]}
]
```

**TODO** : Errorhandling, check if dates meet the requirements, check if it is an empty string `""` etc. The plugin assumes blindly that dates comes as a string in the exact format `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

Test table :

```
<tbody>
    <tr><td>17.11.2014 21:54:39</td></tr>
    <tr><td>18.11.2013 21:54:39</td></tr>
    <tr><td>17.11.2014 1:54:39</td></tr>        
    <tr><td>17.11.2014 1:54:38</td></tr>                
    <tr><td>16.11.2014 22:54:39</td></tr>        
    <tr><td>16.11.2015 00:00:00</td></tr>                
</tbody>
```

Comment: I thought that this format might not be compatible so I downloaded a plugin which theoretically supports multiple new date formats, but after setting sType to that plugin type, nothing changed. After seing your solution, my guess is that it didn't support the date format I'm using either. Thank you for your time, this solved my problem. Cheers.

Comment: Also changed dateParts = a.split('.') to dateParts = a.split(' ')[0].split('.') and removed -1900 in year variable. Could you please explain what was with this -1900? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @Sikor, you are welcome, thank you for accepting the answer! Click on the link above "Date.UTC()" - year is expected to be "_A year after 1900_".  It is just to calculate the correct i.e the same date as integer value. The sorting will of course work either way, since there is no difference in years between say 3913 and 3914 compared to 2013 and 2014..

Comment: `month = parseInt(dateParts[1])-1` though, uodated the answer. Sry for that blunder. Knew it but forgot it.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now but isn't it supposed to be +1900 instead of -1900? It's also a bit strange for me that this function uses 0-11 for months but 1-31 for days (instead of 0-30 for example).

Comment: @Sikor +1900 would give you dates such as 17.11.3914 21:54:39. Yes, years as after 1900, months 0-11 - agree it does not seem very logic, but it is reminiscenses from those days where every bit or byte was essential. Today we are using loooong strings just for unique indexes and so on, we have all the RAM, storage capacity and processing power we could ever dream about - but UTC is back from those days where it made a huge difference if a year could be expressed in two or four digits.

Comment: Seems reasonable :) One last question tho: Is this -1900 correct as well? As of today it would be 2015 - 1900 = 115 which is below 1900 and the function accepts years 1900+. Thanks for all your answers.